# Having trouble to typeaheadjs

Tags: typeahead, typeahead.js

I have used following script :

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" id = "input">
$('#input').typeahead([{name: 'name',remote: 'planets.json',}]);
```

### JSON file

```
{"name" : {"value" : ["4729", "Siva", "Prakash"]},"planets" : {"value" : ["Mercury", "Venus", "Pluto"]}}
```

While typing on the input box , its display two Json array name value[name , plants]. anyway in my code i have mention name as 'name' only. so it has to return that value from 'name' JSON array only ?

Answer (score 0):

In `planets.json` it is name->value, or planets->value. Init the typeahead like this instead :

```
<input type="text" id="input" data-provide="typeahead">

$.getJSON("planets.json", function(json) {
   $('#input').typeahead({ 
     source : json.name.value
   });
});
```

or `json.planets.value`, if you want planets